# I am trying to read below fields from dataframe by using collect action but it was throwing java NullPointer Exception

Tags: scala, hive, apache-spark-sql

```
val db_query="(select
                 a.id,
                 conn_owner,
                 applicationname,
                 IsDuplicateConnection
              from ingestion.connections_metadata
              a inner join ingestion.connectionlnk_data b on
              a.id=b.connection_id inner join ingestion.application c on 
              b.application_id = c.id where a.id =23)db_query"
```

//create df for this

```
val dbname= spark.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("driver",com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
            .option("url",jdbc:sqlserver://sjmnb008hv.in.com:1433/ompm)
            .option("user",MysqlUser)
            .option("password", Password)
            .option("dbtable", db_query)
            .load()
```

//then apply collect on this df

```
dbname.collect.foreach{ x=>
    var owner_name=x.get(1)

    if(x.get(3).toString()=='Y'){
        hive_db = hive_db.tolowerCase() + "_" 
                  + x.get(2).tostring().toLowerCase()
                     .replace(" ","").replace("-","_")
    }
}
```

So here this x.get(3) will taking null value bydefault value is n here.

Comment: why the val_db_query ends like this `d where a.id =23)db_query` ? Do you think the `db_query"` part in here is not needed?

Comment: Thank You for comment I removed it from there but exception is still there actually it was taking null value for x.get(3).toString for isDuplicateConnection field.how I should I replace this null into this if condition kindly suggest.

Comment: do you have data for your condition?

Comment: This issue got resolved on my end thank you for support.